# Unable to get jquery tabs nested

Tags: jquery, tabs

Here is the full sample script which demonstrates the problem, inner tabs company/department come up as list instead of tabs.

Edit:
I have already tried what People have suggested that inner tabs should also be tabified via jQuery but

- it doesn't work
- all the examples I have seen e.g. http://cse-mjmcl.cse.bris.ac.uk/blog/jQueryNestedMenus/nested.html use topmost div for jQuery tabs call.

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //make tabs tabs
    $('#top-tabs').tabs({selected: 2});
});
</script>

</head><body>

<div id="top-tabs">
   <ul>
             <li><a href="/timeapp/home">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="/timeapp/timecard">Timecard</a></li>
             <li><a href="#tab-selected">Config</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="tab-selected">
    <ul>
              <li><a href="#inner-tab-selected">Company</a></li>
              <li><a href="/timeapp/config/department">Department</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="inner-tab-selected">ok this is a company</div>

   </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question at jquery forum and [got the answer](http://www.jqueryhelp.com/viewtopic.php?p=10956#10956).

Reason is that `elem.tabs()` should be called on all inner tabs, the example I gave does it by using jQuery selector e.g. `$('#container ul').tabs()`, so here is the modified working script:

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //make tabs tabs
    $('#top-tabs').tabs({selected: 2});
    $('#low-tabs').tabs({selected: 1});
});
</script>

</head><body>

<div id="top-tabs">
   <ul>
             <li><a href="/timeapp/home">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="/timeapp/timecard">Timecard</a></li>
             <li><a href="#tab-selected">Config</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="tab-selected">
    <div id="low-tabs"> 
    <ul>
              <li><a href="#inner-tab-selected">Company</a></li>
              <li><a href="/timeapp/config/department">Department</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="inner-tab-selected">ok this is a company</div>
     </div> 
   </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is your entire File, then the problem is, your not telling it that the "tab-selected"  div is supposed to be tabs.  I haven't tested it but adding a :

```
 $('#tab-selected').tabs();
```

would probably do the trick.