# Jquery nested tab

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to get jquery tabs nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432928/unable-to-get-jquery-tabs-nested)

I need to create a nested tab. But I didn't got a satisfied solution by google. Can anyone suggest me a solution? I am not a java script or jquery programmer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What solution did google give you? What is the problem with it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432928/unable-to-get-jquery-tabs-nested

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bpJUv/1/

**JS**

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs1').tabs();
$('#tabs2').tabs();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>
            <div id="tabs1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-11">First nested 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-12">Second nested 1</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-11">
                    <p>Content for first nested tab 1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-12">
                    <p>Content for second nested tab 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>
            <div id="tabs2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-21">First nested tab 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-22">Second nested tab 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-21">
                    <p>Content of first nested tab 2</p>
                </div>   
                <div id="tabs-22">
                    <p>Content of second nested tab 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was that a solution for you? :-)